# Angular 8 toggle CSS class using ngFor on click

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have found similar scenarios to this one, but I haven't yet found this exact scenario. Sorry if I missed it.

In Angular 8, I am using an *ngFor to iterate through some message objects. This displays the message title and date/time in a row of vertical boxes to the left of the screen. What I'm trying to get to is when one box is clicked, it becomes active and changes color. I have this working, but the problem is that the "active" class does not inactivate when another box is clicked. This is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Here is my current code with CSS:

```html
<div *ngFor="let msg of messages; let i = index">
  <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" 
      data-toggle="list" href="#home" role="tab" 
      [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isActive}" (click)="popIt(i)">
    <span id="msgSubject1">{{msg.Subject}}</span>
    <br />
    <span class="datetimeCls" id="datetime1">
      {{msg.DateCreated | date : 'short' }}
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

```js
popIt(num: string) {
  var number = num;
  this.SubjectDisplay = this.messages[num].Subject;
  this.DateDisplay = this.messages[num].DateCreated;
  this.TextDisplay = this.messages[num].Body;
}
```

```css
.list-group .list-group-item {
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family:"Gill Sans" Verdana;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.list-group .list-group-item.active {
  background-color: lightgray !important;
  border-top: solid 2px grey;
  border-bottom: solid 2px grey;
  color: grey;
}
```

This displays the object properties as expected, the clicks work, but it makes every box active as they're clicked. They do not inactivate.

Any direction, suggestions or examples would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the relevant code from the component - that's crucial to understanding the problem here.

Comment: `isActive` seems to be a common variable, you need to have something like `msg.isActive` and toggle the same in `popIt()` Pass `msg` directly: `popIt(msg)`

Comment: @KurtHamilton I added the popIt() method, sorry about missing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to have an `activeMessage` property:

```
public activeMessage: Message; // Use the appropriate type here
```

which is set on click and tested in the class binding:

```
<div *ngFor="let msg of messages">
  <a [class.active]="msg === activeMessage"
    (click)="activeMessage = msg; doOtherStuff()" ... >
    ...
  </a>
</div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhoezy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code and store information in your `parent` component about some unique identifier of `message` which was clicked. And then you can easily add click listener to component and inside of `parent` component update stored id. But you have to change a little you HTML `[ngClass]` directive, to return `true` if `message.Id===clickedMessageId`. Or you can store whole message in f.e. `clickedMessage`, then you can do `message===clickedMessage`. Another way you can achieve it, you can create custom `directive` and `service`, when you click `directive` notify `service` to unclick every other object. But you have to remember to remove them from service, once `directive` has been destroyed.